# VBA By ref error and naming rows

Tags: vba, excel

Im starting to get really frustrated. Sometimes it work and sometimes i just get error ByRef Argument type mismatch.

what i also cant get my head around is a problem where im trying to name rows in columns either replanned, delivered or not deliverd. My code is as follows.

Sorry for the messed up codeview, some code are deleted for viewing purpose

ANY help is greatly appriciated.

Sub getAM()
*filters from AM-Shipment in dedicated cell. get data from EKU and thereafter review whetever shipments are trough.

```
Set dataworksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FR")
Set leveranssheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Shipment")

'Clean old data


Lastrow = leveranssheet.Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If Lastrow > 28 Then
leveranssheet.Range(leveranssheet.Cells(29, 1), leveranssheet.Cells(Lastrow, 16)).Clear
End If

'Filter on AM
With Worksheets("ForecastData")
    If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
    .Range("A:K").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="AM"
    .Range("A:K").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=" & "PD" & "*"
    'Filtrera på grupp angiven i ruta:
    .Range("A:K").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="=" & leveranssheet.Cells(2, 5).Value & "*"

    'Cut out columns and place on right position in shipmentsheet.
    Lastrow = .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Lastrow > 1 Then
    'ID, status, description
        .Range(.Cells(1, 2).Offset(rowOffset:=1), .Cells(Lastrow, 4)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        leveranssheet.Range("b29").PasteSpecial
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'Grupp
        .Range(.Cells(1, 8).Offset(rowOffset:=1), .Cells(Lastrow, 8)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        leveranssheet.Range("e29").PasteSpecial
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'Type of delivery
        .Range(.Cells(1, 10).Offset(rowOffset:=1), .Cells(Lastrow, 10)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        leveranssheet.Range("f29").PasteSpecial
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'NExt delivery, Sp, DI
        .Range(.Cells(1, 5).Offset(rowOffset:=1), .Cells(Lastrow, 7)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        leveranssheet.Range("g29").PasteSpecial
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'Resp
        .Range(.Cells(1, 9).Offset(rowOffset:=1), .Cells(Lastrow, 9)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        leveranssheet.Range("j29").PasteSpecial
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'Ordered by
        .Range(.Cells(1, 11).Offset(rowOffset:=1), .Cells(Lastrow, 11)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        leveranssheet.Range("k29").PasteSpecial
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
End With





'Hämtar dagens status från EKU_view
With leveranssheet
Lastrow = .Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Loop trough shipments 
      For i = 29 To Lastrow

          ASMTid = .Cells(i, 2).Value

                    'find correct datecolumns after shipment 

                      Dim milsten3 As Long
                      Dim milsten1 As Variant
                      Dim milsten2 As Variant

                      Set flik = dataworksheet
                      leta = leveranssheet.Cells(i, 6).Value
                      milsten1 = Left(leta, 3)
                      milsten2 = Right(milsten1, 2)
                      milsten3 = "MILESTONE_" & milsten2
                      Debug.Print (milsten3)

                      'name = AlphaNumericOnly(leta)
                      Dim statuskolumn As Long
```

Here i gett my byRef Error

leveranskolumn = kolumnNRAM                             (**milsten3**, flik)
                          Debug.Print ("Leveranskolumn= " & leveranskolumn)

```
                      statuskolumn = kolumnNRASMTstatus(milsten3, flik)
                      Debug.Print ("Statuskolumn= " & statuskolumn)
                    Dim dagensdatum As Date
                  Dim dagensstatus As Date
                  Dim lev As String
                    Dim stat As String


                      If leveranskolumn > 0 Then
                          dagensdatum = dataworksheet.Cells(Rad, leveranskolumn).Value 'Dagens datum för leveransen
                          leveranssheet.Cells(i, 13).Value = IsWeekend(dagensdatum)  'Dagens datum för leveransen

                          If leveranssheet.Cells(i, 13).Value<>                            leveranssheet.Cells(i, 7).Value Then
                              leveranssheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Replanned"
                          End If
                      End If
                      If statuskolumn > 0 Then
                          dagensstatus = dataworksheet.Cells(Rad, statuskolumn).Value 'Dagens datum för leveransen
                          leveranssheet.Cells(i, 12).Value = dagensstatus  'Dagens datum för leveransen
                      End If

                  End If

                  lev = leveranssheet.Cells(i, 6)
                  stat = leveranssheet.Cells(i, 12)


                If leveranssheet.Cells(i, 12).Value >= 1 Then
                    leveranssheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Delivered"
                Else
                    leveranssheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Not Delivered"
                End If
```

Uppdate, This is the codeline that doesnt apply what i want.

```
                      If leveranskolumn > 0 Then
                          dagensdatum = dataworksheet.Cells(Rad, leveranskolumn).Value 'Dagens datum för leveransen
                          leveranssheet.Cells(i, 13).Value = IsWeekend(dagensdatum)  'Dagens datum för leveransen
                          End If
                                                   If statuskolumn > 0 Then
                          dagensstatus = dataworksheet.Cells(Rad, statuskolumn).Value 'Dagens datum för leveransen
                          leveranssheet.Cells(i, 12).Value = dagensstatus

                           If leveranssheet.Cells(i, 12).Value >= 1 Then
                           leveranssheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Delivered"


                         ElseIf leveranssheet.Cells(i, 13).Value <> leveranssheet.Cells(i, 7).Value Then
                              leveranssheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Replanned"


                    Else: leveranssheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Not Delivered"

                          End If

                      End If
```

'Dagens datum för leveransen

Comment: You have declared `milsten3` as Long, but then assign a string to it so you should get a Type Mismatch error there. I can't comment specifically about the ByRef error as you didn't post the code for the routine you call, but it means that they type you are passing is not the type expected.

Comment: THANK U RORY! It worked now. declared my milsten as strings. Do u have any ideas how i can fix my replanned, not delivered, deliverd?

Comment: What is happening is that when i run F8 it seems like it at first prints replanned if the values are as decleared but then the if statements for delivered and not delivered prints over replanned and put not delivered instead.

Comment: Not really as you haven't said what the problem actually is. Best guess you need an `If...ElseIf...ElseIf...End If` clause rather than two separate blocks.

Comment: I have added the failing component Rory. When i run the code the only thing that prints correctly is replanned. not delivered or deilivered just say missing in insto as declared above.

Comment: I suggest you step through the code to figure out why. I can't really tell you  without your workbook.